# A coherent description of wire-attraction without the magnetic force performing work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy, electricity

I am looking for a coherent explanation of wire-attraction, understanding the principle that the magnetic field cannot produce work, microscopically, since to each charge the force is perpendicular to the direction of motion. I toyed with the idea of the carriers banging against the wire like a container, but that didn't make intuitive sense, and still implies a non-external action-reaction pair resulting in work.

Here is my mental model of the situation:

The setup is simple, two long parallel realistic wires in a vacuum carry current in the $+x$-direction, lying in the $x\text{-}y$ plane.

- Via the Biot-Savart law under right-hand rule, the flow in the right wire produces a $\vec{B}$ field pointing in the $+z$-direction at the left wire.
- Via Ørsted-Laplace-Thomson law, $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$, the electrical entities carrying the current in the left wire with the average drift velocity are attracted to the right via the magnetic interaction
- Via charge conservation, Coulomb's law, the law of large numbers, and the externality condition of Newton's second law -- some electrical entities are temporarily offset from the now locally ionized wire and the wire-charge system produces a differential electrical force to the right.
- This entity-offset is the sole mechanism that produces current-wire attraction.

Is this a coherent explanation? is it correct? Where can I read more, or what subfield is this?

One hypothesis about this model is that if the offset could be **completely, elastically** excluded somehow that the current in the left wire would be increased by the incident field, is this known to be the case?

*I've seen lots of adjacent questions with answers ranging from the top answer begging to have the answer removed, to discussion that it's similar to the Hall-effect which can be disproven by confirming that both senses of charge in a current setup like this result in attraction.*

Comment: Did you suppose that charges "*escape*" the wire!? I severely doubt that can happen (at usual scales). More likely you should describe the wire as a heavy, positive, at rest ionic distribution and a light, negative, current carrying electron distribution that get slightly (i.e. subatomically) offset.

Comment: Agreed, words matter and escape is an unfortunate term in this case, thank you @HTNW

Comment: Do these answers help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719643/how-does-the-magnetic-force-exerted-to-moving-electrons-in-a-current-carrying-wi/719674#719674 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412403/work-done-by-magnetic-field-on-current-carrying-conductor/412434#412434